# Is it possibly to have Views with the SAME id in a Tab Layout but in different Tab Contents?

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I am using a Tab layout to display 3 different Content Views however there are several Views (Buttons to be precise) which are common to across all 3 Content Views. Currently I have uniquely identified all the common views e.g.

`android:id=@+id/tab1_button1`

even though they carry out the same function despite which Tab Content is currently displayed.

Is there a way I can maintain the same View id across all the Tab Contents? Is it a matter of just identifying the Views with the same id?

Because I'm Using Tabs I understand that TabHost must be the root node of a Layout therefore I cannot have TabHost within another Layout. Do I understand this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same id across the tabs `android:id=@+id/tab_button1` for `button1` on all the tabs. However it isn't a good design, you'd better extract the similar parts of your layout as include to avoid code duplication. More info [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/02/android-layout-tricks-2-reusing-layouts.html).

Comment: Are you saying it is poor practice to duplicate view Ids or to to duplicate code? While I would agree code duplication is poor practice I would also think duplicate Ids are too. Wouldn't Android become 'confused' as to which view to use is meant if not all of them!

Comment: Android will use the first id, so you'll have to call `findView` directly on each tab layout to obtain proper view. This is true if you'll use `include`s too. Not a big overhead to allow reusing of code IMO.

Comment: Yes I understand you now. I should have realised this when I encountered problems accessing Views in code in each of my individual Tab contents. Unless I specified the Layout view I would get an exception.

Answer (score 0):

As stated [Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#id)

> The XML vocabulary for declaring UI elements closely follows the
>   structure and naming of the classes and methods, where element names
>   correspond to class names and attribute names correspond to methods.
>
> Any View object may have an integer ID associated with it, to uniquely
>   identify the View within the tree.
>
> An ID need not be unique throughout the entire tree, but it should be
>   unique within the part of the tree you are searching (which may often
>   be the entire tree, so it's best to be completely unique when
>   possible).

So you can use same id for any number of views. But best practice should be to use same id for similar views. You just have to remember that you should call `findViewById()` only on a view whose child view you seek to.

If you call `findViewById()` on a view which has more than one child views with same ids, then the behavior is undocumented and its not wise to depend on its current implementation.